# html link should change html of label to checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, label

I have a problem, I have two html links one is 'edit' and the other is 'cancel'.

When edit is pressed in the row, the label which says Yes turn to a drop-down with Options Yes and No, I want to cancel the option when cancel is pressed
and get back the old label.

my html is as follows --

```
<label id="BASADSDMC_13532">Office</label>
```

The id of label in every row is unique

after edit link clicked I add to inner html of where id is BASADSDMC_13532

```
<select>
  <option value="Office">Office</option>
  <option value="Response" selected="">Response</option>
  <option value="NoResponse">No Response</option>
</select>
```

How do I go about it, cancelling the selection and turning it back into old label upon cancel link pressed in a particular row, in jQuery?

Comment: are you using any plugins?

Comment: I am only using jquery with html.

Comment: First, you research the problem you're facing. Then, hopefully, make an attempt at a solution (actual code is good, pseudo-code - to demonstrate you at least recognise the problems/steps - is sometimes great) and then, when that goes wrong (if it does go wrong) come back and ask us a specific question about that specific problem. Show us some code: the relevant ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) HTML, CSS and JavaScript/jQuery, and explain precisely what your code does that shouldn't, and doesn't do that it should.